# How to limit text INPUT length, but not the length itself?

Tags: android, input, dropdown, autocompletetextview, maxlength

I am using `AutoCompleteTextView` and my goal is to allow users to input only 4 symbols and after that choose an item from the drop list.

Comment: in AutoCompleteTextView xml  add `android:maxLength="4"`

Comment: it makes length _copability_ contain no more than 4 symbols. I need `AutoCompleteTextView` capability contain 255 symbols, but user can input only 4

Answer (score 0):

You Can Limit Length programmatically By using `setFilters()`

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> My_arr_adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,items);
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(2);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(My_arr_adapter);
        autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
                autoCompleteTextView.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilter.LengthFilter(255) });
                 autoCompleteTextView.setText(     (String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
                autoCompleteTextView.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilter.LengthFilter(4) });



            }
        });
        autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
             if (charSequence.length()==4){
                 autoCompleteTextView.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilter.LengthFilter(4) });

             }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: No, it still makes `autoCompleteTextView` capable to contain 4 symbols